# How use UITableView to create UI like Apple Music album detail page?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, xcode-storyboard

I want to create a user interface like the Apple Music album detail page in a storyboard. I'm using `UITableView` to show song items, but how do I show cover and other information about the album above the `UITableView`? Using a view or `UITableView` header or something else?

This is what I am trying to implement:

[image: Apple Music album detail page]

I want to know how Apple do this, thanks!

Comment: It’s just another UITableView cell, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a view to the header.

This is how you can achieve this roughly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableView Header to achieve this thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a [TableView header view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview).

But you can also achieve this with a custom TableViewCell at index 0